# Tooltips for dynamic elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm having tooltips on my page

```
var btnArr = ["#b1", "#b2"];
var ttArr = ["Submit", "Clear"];

$.each(btnArr, function (i, v) {
    $(btnArr[i]).prop('title', ttArr[i]);
    $(v).tooltip({
        text: ttArr[i]
    });
});
```

How can I have the tooltips working for dynamically created elements?

Comment: AFAIK neither the jqueryui nor the bootstrap tooltips have a `text` option. What plugin are you using?

Comment: @blgt thanks. I'm using jquery UI. http://jsfiddle.net/dwezvnfy/1/

Comment: you mean the future element ?

Answer (score 1):

You can bind the tooltip widget to a top-level element and use the `items` option to filter what elements you want to show it on:

```
$(document).tooltip({
    items: ".myTooltipButtonClass"
});
```

This could be `document` or a container element or even multiple container elements. The other alternative is to reinstantiate a new widget each time you dynamically create a new button with a tooltip, but that's in most cases unnecessarily complicated

Here's an update on the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h5qbhvmc/

On a side note `text` isn't a valid option and doesn't do anything. [Ref. the list of valid options](https://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/)